# Getting Started with Vote_fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, voting-system

I have successfully installed Vote_fu for rails 3, and have voted for the desired object in the console window, but I'm brand new to rails, so I really don't know how to implement a voting system in the controller. I'm really just looking for some direction, and I'll try to take it from there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is described at [Github's vote_fu page](https://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu)

There are two methods `vote_for` and `vote_against` which you can use in your controller.
Before that, for sure, you have to add `acts_as_voter` and `acts_as_votable` to your models. Thats it